# Avoid Self-Signed JAR

Tags: ssl-certificate, japplet, self-signed, trusted

I have been working on this for roughly 15 hours over the past week.  I am trying to get a java applet on my website.  It keeps blocking it.  I have certified my website via StartSSL.com and my applet with jarsigner, but it still tells me that self-signed applications are blocked.

How can I make this not self signed, but signed by someone else?  I don't want this to work on my computer...I want it to work on everyone's computer.  I have followed about half a dozen tutorials, and still am unsuccessful.  How can I go about getting my Java applet to be on my website in a manner that anyone can run it?

Comment: Are you using the same certificate for the website and the applet? Some certificates don't work for applets (you need the codesign option).

Comment: Where is this information coming from? I have not seen anything in my research except for how to self sign...which does not work.

Comment: See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.12, granted it only applies to X.509 standard. Oh, and if you were asking about how to get this information from your certificate, AFAIK you have to use "keytool" for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you have to pay hundreds of dollars per year to get code signed, and StartSSL.com does not sign code. DigiCert seems the best option at this time.